# Finding the position of center using pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am trying to move an image from its center using pygame. I loaded the image using pygame but I have the top corner coordinates of the image. how do i get the coordinates of center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Rect (and you should be), it's super easy:

```
rect = image.get_rect()
center_pos = rect.center
```

The Rect class has lots of super-useful handles:

```
x,y
top, left, bottom, right
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery
size, width, height
w,h
```

All of them can be assigned to as well:

```
rect.center = (x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also query the size of the image.  Adjust the corner coordinates by half of the size in each direction.